# assets not showing after build process with vite and vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

When running `npm run build` my pictures under `src/assets/...` are not available in the dist directory / production build. So not shown on the site. In dev mode it works for sure.

Any ideas how to make them available after building?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assets in `src/assets` must be referenced in the code (via `import` or similar) to be included in the bundle. If you just want static files to be bundled with your project, you should use `public/` instead:

> Static assets can be handled in two different ways:
>
> - Imported in JavaScript or referenced in templates/CSS via relative paths. Such references will be handled by webpack.
> - Placed in the public directory and referenced via absolute paths. These assets will simply be copied and not go through webpack.

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling

Comment: The imports must be done for every single file in main,js?
Or how should I accomplish this?

If I use the public folder it works just fine. But I'm curious.

Comment: Webpack or equivalent follows all imports and compiles up the resulting files. As a general rule, code goes in src and media in public.

Comment: The provided link has nothing to do with Vite. Please update to: https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html

Answer (score 4):

Vite by default sets the default path to '/', you need to override it to use your project default path for the production build.

Go to your `vite.config.ts` (if you have a JS project instead of TS, it would be `filename.js` instead) and add the `base`; check the example below.

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: '',
})
```

Comment: What does react() do?  Links to the appropriate documentation website would be helpful.